# Perl - How to fix error "Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<)" in if statement

Tags: perl

I am creating a basic bubble sort and I don't understand why i am getting this error Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at line 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = (7,3,5,8,5,2,3,5,7,3,5);
my $length = @nums;

for(my $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        for(my $j = 0; $j < $length; $j++){
                if($nums[$j] lt $nums[$j+1]){
                        my $temp = $nums[$j];
                        $nums[$j] = $nums[$j+1];
                        $nums[$j+1] = $temp;
                }
        }
}
```

It seems to be having issues in the if comparison. I made sure that my array was properly initialized with these values and they are. If i print the values before the for loops they print fine and are initialized.

I assume I am just missing something very simple but I'm honestly lost.

Comment: You should also use `<`, since the `lt` operator performs stringwise comparison. For instance, `13 lt 7` is true because `1` comes before `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner loop, `$j` loops up to `$length-1`. At that point, `$nums[$j]` is the last element of the array. Then you compare it with `$nums[$j+1]` which doesn't exist.